# Accessing views in relative way

Tags: iphone, xcode4, uiviewcontroller

I'm new to xcode and I've one basic question about relative accessing views in ViewController.

Here is the situation in ViewController:

```
View
  1
    1.1
  2
```

Questions:

1. How can I access 2 from View
2. How can I access 1.1 from 2
3. How can I access from 1.1 to View

Thank you very much, single lines of code will be perfect answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You can use tagging. I don't prefer this method but it's fast to implement. See `viewWithTag:`.
2. Or you can save view as instance variables.

Comment: Thanks Cemal for quick answer. In xcode there so nothing like _root, _parent or something like that. I'm using terminology from actionscript, but maybe something similar is also in xcode?

Comment: You could retrieve child views with `[self subviews]` selector. That would return an `NSArray` object. You could iterate over it. For reaching parent view you should use `[self superview]` selector.